# Azure Update Management CentOS - own image

Tags: centos, azure, update

I have an Azure VM running CentOS7 (CentOS 7.6 by Rogue Wave Software).
If I enable Update Management and schedule an update, it does what it is supposed to do.  Inclusions and exclusions work, updates are installed.

If I setup another VM running CentOS7, but this time using my own image, not the one provided on Azure, the updates do not install.  Everything is enabled, the schedule does work, but all updates show as "Not selected".  I tried different inclusion definitions, always the same result.

So my guess is that my image is missing something provided in the CentOS 7.6 by Rogue Wave Software image.  Any idea what?

Additionnal information, on my image, in Update Management, the "Update agent readiness" says "Disconnected".  I ran the troubleshoot checks and they all return OK.  So no problem is indicated here.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs a response later...

**Currently (June 2019):**
- CentOS does not know if patches are critical, security or other.
- Azure does!  They look up the patches on CentOS and if there is a relation to RedHat classification they show it in Update Management. 
- However you cannot ask Azure to patch the CentOS since when it sends the command to update, CentOS still does not know what to patch.

**So the solution is (well the one we use):**
- Get a list of all the updates reported by Azure for system X, filtering on critical and security updates
- Export it as a CSV
- Write a script that takes the CSV and extracts the package name with the exact version number
- For each package, run `yum  -y upgrade-to PACKAGE`.  Once per package, so yum installs only that one package, at that version.

This way, when Azure scans the system later, it will see that the updates are installed.  And CentOS will apply only the critical / security patches, as reported by Azure.